# How to download a specific DIV from a site using cURL?

Tags: php, function, html, curl

I'm learning PHP and I wanted to know how to download a specific DIV every one or two hour automatically via cURL from a website.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You download the whole page, then parse it for the specific DIV you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED (may be errors):

```
set_time_limit(3600*24); //24 hours

$numDownloads = 12; 

for ($i = 0; $i < $numDownloads; $i++) 
{
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (preg_match('/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/i', $content, $matches)) 
    {
        $divContents = $matches[1];

        $myFile = 'div'.$i.'.txt'; 

        if ($fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')) 
        {
            fwrite($fh, $divContents) 
        } 

        fclose($fh);
    }


    sleep(3600*2); 
}
```

I suggest you drop the loop and run that on a cron job though....

Comment: lol ... I'm a total noob ... how to drop a loop xD ? - and can I specify a div ?

Comment: To remove the loop, you would take out this code: `for ($i = 0; $i < $numDownloads; $i++) 
{ }`. The div can be specified on this line: `if (preg_match('/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/i', $content, $matches)) `. The only problem with that is you div must have an id or something unique about it. Also, you should really really really learn the basics of PHP before you use this code. Not knowing how to remove a loop is only gonna cause you more headaches later.

Comment: Thanks for the info ... I have started learning it via W3Schools ;-)

Comment: I would stay away from that man.. I can't find the post where I found this on here, but check out http://w3fools.com, they have a bunch of valid points.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the page with cURL, and parse it with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to find what you need.

[`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) might be the fastest way to find what you are looking for.